# SQL Full Text Search - Special Characters

Tags: sql, t-sql, escaping, full-text-search, special-characters

I have been given a database to look after that is configured for Full Text Searching.  Unfortunately, I've limited experience with this and an issue has come in where a search like this '"AT&T"' brings back the correct search results but searching for '"AT&"' brings back results that contain "AT" and not "AT&".

I'm presuming this is because the "&" symbol is a special character(?)

My query (that works correctly) is:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [DB_dev].[dbo].[Info] WHERE CONTAINS(Description, '"AT&T"')
```

Brings back only rows with a description containing "AT&T".

The query I'm having issue with is:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [DB_dev].[dbo].[Info] WHERE CONTAINS(Description, '"AT&"')
```

Brings back any row containing a description of "AT".

NOTE: I am using SQL Server 2014 and have tried escaping with the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [DB_dev].[dbo].[Info] WHERE CONTAINS(Description, '"AT&&"')

SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [DB_dev].[dbo].[Info] WHERE CONTAINS(Description, '"AT%&"')

SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [DB_dev].[dbo].[Info] WHERE CONTAINS(Description, '"AT\&"')

SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [DB_dev].[dbo].[Info] WHERE CONTAINS(Description, '"AT[&]"')
```

None of which work (find "A&").

Comment: what dbms are you using, what is the desired output from the last statement?

Comment: Apologies, I should have stated - SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually full-text engines will not index the text as is but perform some analysis on it:

- words segmentation (spaces, dashes,...)
- discarding some characters and words (the, a,...)
- regroup terms (govern, government, governing,...)

All this depends on engine and configuration.

First you must found out what exaclty is indexed: is 'AT&T' indexed as ('AT' and 'T') or ('AT T') or ('AT&T'). Then if it is 'AT&T' and the '&' is discarded you must escape it in your query using the DB specific escape character. For instance if the escape character is '\' it could be 'AT\&T'. On some other engines you will have to force the whole world like "AT&T" (with quotes).

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014.  Does anyone know the escape character for that?  It might be that the "&" is not indexed.  Does anyone know how I force it to be indexed?

Comment: You need to find out the escape character, for now your query looks like this :where Description like 'AT%' and you want where Description like  'AT[&]' ....i am not sure this is how you escape in your dbms.

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with SQL Server.

Comment: Why this post was accepted as an answer? It does not answer OPs question which is was related to SQL Server.